# Automatic checking for status of a column in mysql daily at a particular time and then updating column of that table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am trying to achieve following

Checking a STATUS column of a particular table everyday at say MIDNIGHT and then Updating Status to a new status if condition is matched else do nothing....

Is there a way to create a TRIGGER to achieve this?

Comment: You want to set up a cron job to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this in sql database itself using tigger or some procedure?

Comment: Check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff creating a cron job isn't portable across operating systems, and also requires additional privileges outside of MySQL.
EVENTs, as suggested by Riad, on the other hand are portable and only require a MySQL account with the required privileges, but nothing external to MySQL itself ...